# Java JDBC is not reusing String values?

Tags: java, string, jdbc, jvm

My colleague and I are having some memory issues with an application, and one discovery we made is String values coming from a database (which are highly duplicative) are actually not being interned. Hence duplicate values are held in memory which could potentially be a huge problem.

For instance, here is a simple JDBC example querying identical Strings from a SQLite database. I print the identity hash code of each one, and it shows each is a separate instance.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        try
        {
            // create a database connection
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/C:/rexon_metals.db");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT REGION FROM CUSTOMER WHERE REGION = 'Southwest'");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                String region = rs.getString("REGION");
                System.out.println(region + ": " + System.identityHashCode(region));
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            // if the error message is "out of memory",
            // it probably means no database file is found
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if(connection != null)
                    connection.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                // connection close failed.
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Southwest: 405662939
Southwest: 653305407
Southwest: 1130478920
Southwest: 1404928347
```

But if I explicitly call the `String.intern()` method, all the identity hash codes are the same.

```
String region = rs.getString("REGION").intern();
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Southwest: 405662939
Southwest: 405662939
Southwest: 405662939
Southwest: 405662939
```

Why does the JDBC does not call `intern()` for me? Is this something expected for the developer to do in the event there are many duplicative `String` values? That are used frequently and persisted throughout the application's session?

P.S. - There are millions of String values which could be consolidated to a few hundred. Does this warrant manual intern() calls then?

Comment: I don't know why you're surprised; I have never seen anything to indicate that the Java runtime analyzes strings to determine when `.intern()` would be useful. Especially since you can do this down when the database query is called, it certainly appears it would be a good idea.

Comment: Now that I'm actually thinking about it, I don't know why I am surprised either. I kind of assumed the JVM would do magical optimizations for me. Now that I'm actually considering how persistence would have to occur, I can see why it does not happen automatically necessarily.

Comment: Actually, there is such a "magical" optimization: `-XX:+UseStringDeduplication` which can be used with G1 garbage collector.

Comment: BTW, using `intern()` for deduplication is a bad idea. A simple `ConcurrentHashMap` is almost always a better choice. See [this presentation](https://youtu.be/YgGAUGC9ksk?t=1739) for details.

Comment: In older versions of the JDK (pre JDK 7) there are memory limitations for where interned strings are stored. They go to the reserved **Permanent Generation** area of the JVM. The size of this area is limited, and is usually much smaller than the heap. JDK 7+ now uses the main java heap to store interned strings. In my opinion, since the JDBC won't know how much will actually ever be interned I don't think it wants to risk doing this automatically for you since you can do this yourself and bloat storage space on your own terms especially when talking in millions strings.

Comment: I'll need to play with these solutions. Interesting...

Comment: @apangin it sounds like your +UseStringDeduplication suggestion is the most promising. I'll tell my coworker to try this on Monday. Considering how data-driven our applications are,  and the duplicative nature of our data, this might be worthwhile enabling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JDBC driver does not intern String data you retrieve from the database.

You need to consider that interning is relatively expensive, and the driver cannot easily predict which data is highly repetitive and which is not - especially since a JDBC result set is most likely streamed in bit by bit from the database while the client code traverses it.

If memory is a major bottleneck for your application *and* your String data is highly repetitive you can manually intern() it. Beware that this will still not prevent the Strings to be created by the driver, the only thing that changes is that copies would become garbage collectable as soon as they go out of scope.

But if you have such repeated Strings in your database, I would certainly look if the database is designed properly *first*. If it turns out that the Strings actually represent a fixed set, consider turning them into a table of codes which can be represented by e.g. just an id.

Comment: Thanks I was wondering about database design and normalizing the strings to ID's in a separate table. It would make the database more esoteric although efficient, and the former could be mitigated by views. I'd still have to pull data as one comprehensive set rather than on-demand for individual records, but that is necessary to minimize excessive object creation. I'll consider and weigh all the advice in this post. Thanks all!

Comment: Might be worth emphasizing that this is specific to the particular driver, e.g. sqlite in this case. A different driver may canonicalize Strings (which doesn’t have to be via `intern()`), though most drivers don’t (from my experience).

Comment: We found that Guava has a streamlined utility for interning too https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Interners.html#newWeakInterner()